# Dynamically allocated member pointer is not zero initialized?

Tags: c++, c++20, member-pointers

Consider the following code, where `T` is a member pointer:

```
#include <cassert>

struct Foo { double v = 0; };

int main()
{
  using T = double Foo::*;

  T p1 = nullptr;
  T p2 = T();
  T p3{};
  T * pp4 = new T();
  T * pp5 = new T{};

  assert(p1 == p2);
  assert(p1 == p3);
  assert(p1 == *pp4); // Fails on MSVC
  assert(p1 == *pp5); // Fails on MSVC

  delete pp4;
  delete pp5;
}
```

clang and gcc compile and run this without problems (live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WKds9noxx)). However, MSVC (e.g. in version 19.35, but also others) does not: It compiles, but the asserts for `pp4` and `pp5` fail. If I understand the cppreference for [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) correctly, `pp4` and `pp5` should be [zero initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), where in turn I would expect the resulting value to compare equal to `nullptr`. Printing the values to `cout` shows that all values are 0, except for `pp4` and `pp5` which are 1. Is this a MSVC bug, or is my understanding of member pointers and reading the cppreference wrong?

Background: Of course, having dynamically allocated member pointers is rather uncommon. I stumbled upon this while testing whether my [`tiny::optional`](https://github.com/Sedeniono/tiny-optional) can cope with member pointers (`optional<double Foo::*>`). Internally, the library uses placement new to construct the value, which shows the same issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sadly, the MSVC execution is disabled on godbolt for quite some time now. See https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/4769. So in my link, clang and gcc execute the code, MSVC does not. (The option is greyed out.) But all 3 compile the code.

Comment: Alright, tested with my local copy and was able to reproduce.

Comment: MSVC's member pointers are not standard-conforming by default for backwards-compatibility reasons, if I remember correctly. I don't remember the details anymore though.

Comment: Value-initialization of member pointers has always been broken on MSVC, and it's not a matter of defaults – there is no flag to fix it. This is why Boost has `BOOST_NO_COMPLETE_VALUE_INITIALIZATION` defined for MSVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MSVC is not standard conformant** here because `T = double Foo::*` is a **scalar type** and `new T()` is value initialization which will result in zero initialization in this case.

This can be seen from [value initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.general#8):

> To value-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> - (8.1)
> - (8.2)
> - (8.3) **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized**.

This means that *zero initialization* will be performed here.

---

Next, from [zero initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.general#6):

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if `T` is a **scalar type (6.8.1), the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal `0` (zero) to** `T`;83

---

This means that the effect is the same as if we were to write `T * pp4 = 0;` and `T * pp5 = 0`. Thus, `pp4` and `pp5` both should compare equal to `nullptr`.